# Restricting the App installion in Tab devics

Tags: android, android-studio, tabs, android-manifest

Using  below code am trying to restrict  App installation  in tab from play store but its not working it allowing to install from play store. It should allow only mobiles to install.

<manifest

<supports-screens

```
    android:normalScreens="true"

    android:smallScreens="true"

    android:largeScreens="false"

    android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7353455?hl=en#zippy=%2Cmanage-excluded-devices-per-app follow this tutorial

Comment: i want restrict code through manifest file only..